# SSH connection in shell script with an user

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, centos

I two CentOS 6.5 servers and I have a very complex shell script connecting this two servers and make some backups with root user without password. There is some rsa keys for this. 
For security purpes I disabled root login on both servers and I tried to change the script to use a user insted of root but it's doesen't work. I have changed the user rights from /etc/sudoers to user    ALL=(ALL) ALL. 
If I generate another ssh key with ssh-keygen -t rsa it say me that I don't have permisson and if I use sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa he create me a key for root@server.
I think the problem will be solve if I can change the user rights to run sudo comands without "sudo", like root but I don't know if this it's possible.
Thanks!

Comment: If you'd like help with your script, please show us your script.  Without the code you need help with, this is not a programming question and is therefore off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain security, yet to accomplish this certain work, you need to do the followings:

1. Create a new user account, for this certain work only.
2. Give this user an ssh-key to automatically login without password.
3. The login shell should not be /bin/bash, for obvious security
   reason.  You can setup SSH connection to run certain program/command
   for this specific user.  I don't want to explain the details here. 
   Please search the web for the answer for this.
4. Since this program needs root permission, and this user is not the
   root, you need to setup an effective executable permission as
   root (i.e. setuid).  To make it only executable by this certain user (and root),
   you need to create a new group, set this user to join this group,
   and set the program to be executable by this group (chmod 4770,  4
   for setuid, 770 to be executable by the group, and the owner).  The
   program must be owned by root (so that it setuid to root), with the group assigned
   to that certain group. The program can be a binary-executable, or a script.
   That does not matter.
5. Caution: Your setuid program/script must be very careful not to
   contain exploitable security weaknesses.